# Conflict with JQuery on Symfony 3 while submitting form

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, forms, symfony

This is my first question to the community but I've been reading a lot of posts from you guys and they helped me quite a lot ! :)

I've been learning PHP for a couple of months and I have an issue I cannot solve. I feel kind of lost even though I think I found the source of the conflict.

Everything works fine BEFORE I add JQuery. 
When I add JQuery:, my form tells me if there is an empty field (it checks the required fields) but the button doesn't work anymore so the data is never sent and persisted into the database.

I used JQuery to customize form on previous projets and everything worked fine.

Code for my form (generated by crud command on terminal) which works without Jquery.

```
{{ form_start(form) }}
    {{ form_widget(form) }}
    <input type="submit" value="Create" />
{{ form_end(form) }}
```

My JS block

```
{% block javascripts %}

<script src="{{ asset('Design/js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js') }}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset ('Design/js/materialize.min.js') }}"></script>
<script src="{{ asset('Design/js/globalscript.js') }}"></script>
{% endblock %}
```

Maybe I did something wrong because on previous projects it worked fine. But I'm new to coding and I don't know where to look anymore. I cannot find topics that enlighten me so I'm asking you for some advice !

UPDATE Controller :

```
/**
 * Creates a new song entity.
 *
 * @Route("/new", name="music_song_new")
 * @Method({"GET", "POST"})
 */
public function newAction(Request $request)
{
    $song = new Song();
    $form = $this->createForm('WeSoundBundle\Form\Music\SongType', $song);
    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {

        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $playerEditor = $this->get('app.player_editor');
        $song->setSongUrl($playerEditor->getYoutubeId($song->getSongPlayer()));
        $em->persist($song);
        $em->flush();

        return $this->redirectToRoute('music_song_show', array('id' => $song->getId()));
    }

    return $this->render('music/song/new.html.twig', array(
        'song' => $song,
        'form' => $form->createView(),
    ));
}
```

My form type:

```
namespace WeSoundBundle\Form\Music;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;

class SongType extends AbstractType
{
/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder->add('songTitle')->add('songArtist')->add('album')->add('songPlayer')->add('songLyrics')->add('songPopularity');
}
    /**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults(array(
        'data_class' => 'WeSoundBundle\Entity\Music\Song'
    ));
}

/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
public function getBlockPrefix()
{
    return 'wesoundbundle_music_song';
}
}
```

Thanks,

YD

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, please add information about your controller and how you build your form. Make sure to read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Btw, do you recognize you are including two different versions of jquery?

Comment: Hello !
Thank you for your reply and greetings ! :)
I tried to keep only the relevant information as they explain me to do on your link. I hope what I share is correct and will help you better understand. 
I add the controller part for the newAction and the formType. 
Everything works fine without JQuerry but it stops working when I add it (I removed the CDN version in my project but before I came here I tried with one version, two or zero).
It makes me crazy because I cannot understand why JQuerry is crashing my form while it didn't crash it in previous projects.

Comment: anything in `Design/js/globalscript.js` that could mess up the form?

Comment: I thought the file was empty but forgot I put some code for a future login modal... I tried without JS and without JQuery but didn't try without my custom JS...  SMH... 
Thank you so much ! Now it works perfectly ! :)